# Elgg - extend widget title - switch content via ajax

Tags: php, elgg

I have an Elgg site with a dashboard view of widgets.

I need to extend the posts & articles view as follows:
extend the widget title to display 3 links:
recent posts | popular posts | starred posts
and switch the widget content when clicking a link

Does someone have an experience or a clue how to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add links to the *title*, you need to override object/widget view. You could put these as the tabs in widget content though.

To refresh the widget content, you need to write your own JS that gets view of the widget. You may register object/widget as ajax refreshable view (elgg_register_ajax_view) and than call ajax/view/object/widget?guid=XX (see elgg.get function in JS)

I do widget reloading in [this plugin](http://community.elgg.org/plugins/1158489/1.0/core-version),  have a look at it as an example. It will need some changes for your case though.